# PHP: define() class scoped constants

Tags: php, constants

I am building a class that turns a flatfile into a virtual database, I am trying to take the values of an array as the column names instead of indexes when retrieving data like so...

```
$db = new Database($config, array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'), true);
```

The array is sent to the constructor in **database.php:**

```
public function __construct(Config $config, array $constants = null, $caseInsensitive = false)  {
            $this->_config = $config;
            if(!is_null($constants))
                $this->defineColumns($constants, $caseInsensitive);
            return true;
        }
```

Which is passed on to `defineColumns()`:

```
private function defineColumns($constants, $caseInsensitive) {
            for ($i=0;$i<count($constants);$i++)
                define($constants[$i], $i, $caseInsensitive);   
        }
```

This works and I can now use `first` to access column 0, `second` to access column 1 and so on...

However the `define()` function seems to make the constants global and accessible from outside the class instance.

I want each set of declared constants to be scoped to the instance alone allowing me to use the same constant again in another instance of the class to access a different column.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid is not possible if you want to use constants. Constants are global.

By not using constants, you can store that names in a class static member and use them with something like `$myinstance->get('third')`.

```
protected static $columns = array();

private function defineColumns($constants) {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($constants);$i++)
        self::$columns[$constants[$i]] = $i;    
}

public function get($column) {
    return $IDONTKNOWYOURIMPLEMENTATION[ self::$columns[$column] ];
}
```

Comment: Sneaky thanks I was expecting to use strings not constants that's just bad wording on my behalf, I'm not gonna make it static but it works the same :)